# Long dropdown menu causes scrolling on the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic menu with the CSS below. The full code is on Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/9drons8g/).

```
#
cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li, #cssmenu span, #cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}#
cssmenu {
    line - height: 1;
    border - radius: 5 px 5 px 0 0; - moz - border - radius: 5 px 5 px 0 0; - webkit - border - radius: 5 px 5 px 0 0;

    width: auto;
}#
cssmenu: after, #cssmenu ul: after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}#
cssmenu a {
    background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, # 333333 0 % ,
    #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, # 333333), color - stop(100 % , #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, # 333333 0 % , #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, # 333333 0 % , #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, # 333333 0 % , #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, # 333333 0 % , #141414 100%);
  color: # ffffff; display: block; font - family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans - serif; padding: 19 px 20 px; text - decoration: none;
}#
cssmenu ul {
    list - style: none;
}#
cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline - block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}#
cssmenu.align - center {
    text - align: center;
}#
cssmenu.align - center > ul > li {
    float: none;
}#
cssmenu.align - center ul ul {
    text - align: left;
}#
cssmenu.align - right > ul {
    float: right;
}#
cssmenu.align - right ul ul {
    text - align: right;
}#
cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font - size: 12 px;
}#
cssmenu > ul > li: hover: after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50 % ;
        bottom: 0;
        border - left: 10 px solid transparent;
        border - right: 10 px solid transparent;
        border - bottom: 10 px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
# cssmenu > ul > li: first - child > a {
            border - radius: 5 px 0 0 0; - moz - border - radius: 5 px 0 0 0; - webkit - border - radius: 5 px 0 0 0;
        }#
        cssmenu.align - right > ul > li: first - child > a,
        #cssmenu.align - center > ul > li: first - child > a {
            border - radius: 0; - moz - border - radius: 0; - webkit - border - radius: 0;
        }#
        cssmenu.align - right > ul > li: last - child > a {
            border - radius: 0 5 px 0 0; - moz - border - radius: 0 5 px 0 0; - webkit - border - radius: 0 5 px 0 0;
        }#
        cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
        #cssmenu > ul > li: hover > a {
            color: #ffffff;
            box - shadow: inset 0 0 3 px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px # 000000; - webkit - box - shadow: inset 0 0 3 px #000000;
  background: # 070707;
            background: -moz - linear - gradient(top, #262626 0%, # 070707 100 % );
            background: -webkit - gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color - stop(0 % , #262626), color-stop(100%, # 070707));
            background: -webkit - linear - gradient(top, #262626 0%, # 070707 100 % );
            background: -o - linear - gradient(top, #262626 0%, # 070707 100 % );
            background: -ms - linear - gradient(top, #262626 0%, # 070707 100 % );
            background: linear - gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, # 070707 100 % );
        }#
        cssmenu.has - sub {
            z - index: 1;
        }#
        cssmenu.has - sub: hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }#
        cssmenu.has - sub ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            min - width: 200 px;
            top: 100 % ;
            left: 0;
        }#
        cssmenu.align - right.has - sub ul {
            left: auto;
            right: 0;
        }#
        cssmenu.has - sub ul li { * margin - bottom: -1 px;
        }#
        cssmenu.has - sub ul li a {
            background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted # 31 b7f1;
            font - size: 11 px;
            filter: none;
            display: block;
            line - height: 120 % ;
            padding: 10 px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }#
        cssmenu.has - sub ul li: hover a {
                background: #0c7fb0;
}
# cssmenu ul ul li: hover > a {
                    color: #ffffff;
                }#
                cssmenu.has - sub.has - sub: hover > ul {
                    display: block;
                }#
                cssmenu.has - sub.has - sub ul {
                    display: none;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 100 % ;
                    top: 0;
                }#
                cssmenu.align - right.has - sub.has - sub ul,
                #cssmenu.align - right ul ul ul {
                    left: auto;
                    right: 100 % ;
                }#
                cssmenu.has - sub.has - sub ul li a {
                    background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted # 31 b7f1;
                }#
                cssmenu.has - sub.has - sub ul li a: hover {
                        background: #0a6d98;
}
# cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
                        #cssmenu ul ul li: last - child > a,
                        #cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
                        #cssmenu ul ul ul li: last - child > a,
                        #cssmenu.has - sub ul li: last - child > a,
                        #cssmenu.has - sub ul li.last > a {
                            border - bottom: 0;
                        }
```

My problem is that when there are large product categories, the menu list becomes very long and causes problems with scrolling on the page.

I have tried to solve the problem (Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/rw75p5q7/)) but it is not working. Can you please help?

Comment: I am getting wrong by mixing two of these into jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/axzo3k2g/

Comment: "*it goes wrong"* What going wrong?

Comment: It does not menu scrolling like as link two.

Comment: I dont find any thing wrong http://jsfiddle.net/rw75p5q7/1/.. Is this what you want right?

Comment: I am trying to adding this scrolling with my sub menu into http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/9drons8g/ , 


I have tried to implement menu scrolling to this , the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/axzo3k2g/

Comment: so you need 2/3 level scrolling menu?

Comment: Yes. Not 2/3 it might be more. It will come from my user product category.  For this reason I am 

Just adding this menu scrolling into first link of my post.

Comment: Grammar. Exposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this demo, this is what you were expecting right. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/9drons8g/2/)

```
var maxHeight = 170;
$(function(){

    $("#cssmenu ul li ul li").hover(function() {

         var $container = $(this),
             $list = $container.find("ul"),
             $anchor = $container.find("a"),
             height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
             multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller

        // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
        $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

        // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
        $anchor.addClass("hover");

        // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
        $list
            .show()
            .css({
                paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
            });

        // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
        if (multiplier > 1) {
            $container
                .css({
                    height: maxHeight,

                })
                .mousemove(function(e) {
                    var offset = $container.offset();
                    var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                    if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                        $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                    };
                });
        }

    }, function() {

        var $el = $(this);

        // put things back to normal
        $el
            .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
            .find("ul")
            .css({ top: 0 })
            .hide()
            .end()
            .find("a")
            .removeClass("hover");

    });

    // Add down arrow only to menu items with submenus
    $(".dropdown > li:has('ul')").each(function() {
        $(this).find("a:first").append("i");
    });

    });
```

Comment: It is working but goes one level down of top previous level's sub menu. And all sub menu is expanding automatically. Yet ++, Try to fixed this.

Comment: Replace this line of code $("#cssmenu ul li ul li ul li").hover(function() {

Comment: $("#cssmenu ul li ul li ul li") it could not be changed as others, because there may two level, three level or four level menu. has-sub class mean there are sub menu, so it could not be used only for has-sub class, where contains has-sub class, it would be scroll able. I am trying to tell you using  $("#cssmenu ul li ul li ul li") to similar as $(".has-sub")

Comment: If you need to achieve the above scenario, Make your code to work in conditions like if(){}else{}.

Comment: @ stanze, Dear Boss, I have changed your js code as var maxHeight = $(window).height()-350;//170; $(function() $(".has-sub ul li").hover(function() { 

It is going top of my main menu
When it will go top of my main menu or below of my main menu it will hide, Actually it will display 5 items, if there are more items then it may add a scroll or hide.  like as http://jsfiddle.net/kabircse/rw75p5q7/